# How do I get from a few sub equations to a final equation?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a few start equation like Z1 and Z2 in the S domain. How can I use Mathematica to get the final equation? Including the index numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One possible way

```
Clear["Global`*"];
z1 = r1 + 1/(C1*s);
z2 = r2 (1/(c2*s))/(r2 + 1/(c2*s));
eq = Simplify[(z1 + z2)/z1]
eq = Collect[Numerator[eq], s]/Collect[Denominator[eq], s]
```

[image]

If you want high powers of polynomials to be on left side, use

```
TraditionalForm[eq]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, saves me a lot of work.